# Tkinter - Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Python Programming 3rd Ed.
isbn 978-1-4354-5500-9

The following code will not work for me, can anyone help me?

I'm very new to Tkinter and GUI...any advice or resources would be appreciated

Thanks, Adam

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.myButton = Button(self, text='Button Label')
        self.myButton.grid()

root = Tkinter.Tk()

root.title('Frame w/ Button')
root.geometry('200x200')

app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is there any error message? Please provide full traceback if possible.

Comment: By any chance did you name your file "Tkinter.py"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer....Thanks for the comments

```
class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.myButton = Button(self, text='Button Label')
        self.myButton.grid()

    root = Tkinter.Tk()

    root.title('Frame w/ Button')
    root.geometry('200x200')

    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3.x, `Tkinter` module is renamed to `tkinter`:

```
try:
    # Python 3.x
    from tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    # Python 2.x
    from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.myButton = Button(self, text='Button Label')
        self.myButton.grid()

root = Tk()

root.title('Frame w/ Button')
root.geometry('200x200')

app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**UPDATE** changed the code to run both in Python 2.x, Python 3.x.

Comment: my computer only works for 'Tkinter'...an error shows up for 'tkinter'

Comment: @ARW, Are you sure you're using Python 3.x.  What `python -V` prints?

Comment: Version 3.5.0a4 (3.5.0a4)

Comment: @ARW, How do you run your script? In command line, or double click?

Comment: Here's the screenshot I got with the code in the answer with Python 3.5b4 + Ubuntu 15.04: http://i.imgur.com/YceIrEQ.png

Comment: line 12, in __init__super(Application, self).__init__(master)
TypeError: must be type, not classobj

Comment: @ARW, Maybe you're using Python 2.x. The code in this answer is meant to be run in Python 3.x.

Comment: @ARW, Now fixed the code to run both in Python 2.x and in Python 3.x. (by catching `ImportError` and to use `Frame.__init__` instead of `super`. Thank you for comment.